# Write a StringBuilder to a Writer, without toString()

Tags: java, servlets, stringbuilder, printwriter

In a Servlet, I am building a very large amount of HTML content in a StringBuilder that, at the end, needs to be written to the response's PrintWriter. In order to use a PrintWriter, it must first call StringBuilder's toString() method to get the content as a String. But this unnecessarily duplicates the content. Is there some way to directly write from the StringBuilder since it already is holding the content?

PrintWriter can accept a CharSequence, but the documentation states it calls the CharSequence's toString(), so it doesn't really help.

The only clear way I can see is to use StringBuilder's charAt(i) method to get and write one character at a time, but would this be an improvement?

Comment: Improvement is relative. If your goal is to reduce the memory consumption, then yes it would be an improvement. You should test if it's slower. I wouldn't be surprised if - due to the buffering of the output stream - the performance penalty wasn't that big after all.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative, you could drop the StringBuilder and use a [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) and a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Comment: I need to take the HTML content and write it to the Servlet's PrintWriter, which is obtained by calling the HttpServletResponse's getWriter() method. I don't see a way to combine this with a StringWriter.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write to the PrintWriter in the first place rather than to the StringBuilder...

Using `charAt` would definitely not help you. It would yield very poor performance to do it this way.
If you *really* want to proceed in that direction you *could* use the `StringBuilder.subString(start,end)` method. This method will allow you to read for example 1000 characters at a time and print it to the PrintWriter...

Comment: `StringBuilder.substring()` will allocate a new String each time you call it. Although the total amount of memory allocated will be smaller, it sill imposes a lot of overhead. I would actually think that using charAt() won't be that bad because most probably the Servlet's PrintWriter is buffered anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The `StringBuilder` class stores the string in an internal char array. The problem is that this char array is not accessible.

Proposed solutions:

1) You could create a new class extending `ObjectOutputStream`, where you override the `writeObjectOverride(Object obj)` method. Then simply serialize the `StringBuilder` instance in which you have constructed your HTML document.
Your overridden `writeObjectOverride(Object obj)` method will be called with the internal char array of the `Stringbuilder` which is part of the serialization process, and voila: you have the reference to the internal char array of the String builder, it's yours to write it to the Servlet's PrintWriter output... *Note:* your `writeObjectOverride()` method will be called multiple times, obviously you can disregard the ones which pass you something other than the desired char array.

2) You could use the `CharBuffer` class instead of `StringBuilder` which has `array()` method returning the internal array. `CharBuffer` does not have as many append (or put) operations as the `StringBuilder`, so it would require to extend those a little bit (depending on what you need exactly)...

3) You could write your own implementation of `StringBuilder`, or rather what you use from it. That way you would have access to the object (a char array for example) in which you store the assembled text...

Comment: I'm not sure solution 1 would work because to use writeObjectOverride you need to rewrite most of the serialization logic because the one parameter ObjectOutputStream constructor disables the call to writeObjectOverride. i.e. it's not designed to be used that way. Also there are no other methods that you could call within writeObjectOverride to handle the normal case. You could use reflexion though but the security manager could get in your way.